# SelectList with OptGroup in asp.net MVC 5.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a SelectList in my asp.net MVC 5.2 web app with all items of a database. MVC 5.2 allows to use `<optgroup>`. Now I want to have optgroups with the property Type (string). How’s the syntax for this? Everything works except the `.group` part. I have realy no clue how to do this.

The code to create the SelectList:

```
Public Shared Function getNameList() As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
   Dim DB As New ModelDB
   Return DB.Things.ToList().[Select](Function(item) New SelectListItem() With {
                                                     .Text = item.Name,
                                                     .Value = item.ID,
                                                     .Group = item.Type})  'ERROR in this line
End Function
```

The error is:

> Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListGroup'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess I found a solution after hours of trying:

```
Public Shared Function getNameList() As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
    Dim DB As New ModelDB
    'sort alphabetically
    Dim sortList As IEnumerable(Of Model) = From item In DB.Model.ToList() Order By item.Name Order By item.Type
    'create list of SelectListGroup
    Dim OptGroups As List(Of SelectListGroup) = sortList.Select(Function(item) item.Type).Distinct().Select(Function(type) New SelectListGroup With {.Name = type}).ToList()
    'define selectList
    Dim selectList As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem) = sortList.[Select](Function(item) New SelectListItem() With {
                                           .Text = item.Name,
                                           .Value = item.ID,
                                           .Group = OptGroups.First(Function(type) type.Name = item.Type)})

    Return selectList
End Function
```

I hope someone can profit from this code.

Comment: The part where you assign it to an actual SelectList is missing, but this is how I did it. Dim list = New SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text", "Group.Name", defaultValue)